# how to take the specific details out in Python that are separated by a semi colon or a slash?

Tags: python

I have the following results from a vet analyser

> result{type:PT/APTT;error:0;PT:32.3 s;INR:0.0;APTT:119.2;code:470433200;lot:405
>   4H0401;date:20/01/2017 06:47;PID:TREKKER20;index:015;C1:-0.1;C2:-0.1;qclock:0;ta
>   rget:2;name:;Sex:;BirthDate:;operatorID:;SN:024000G0900046;version:V2.8.0.09}

Using Python how do i separate the date the time the type PT and APTT.... please note that the results will be different everytime so i need to make a code that will find the date using the / and will get the time because of four digits and the : .... do i use a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code makes further usage of fields easier by converting them to `dict`.

```
from pprint import pprint

result = "result{type:PT/APTT;error:0;PT:32.3 s;INR:0.0;APTT:119.2;code:470433200;lot:405 4H0401;date:20/01/2017 06:47;PID:TREKKER20;index:015;C1:-0.1;C2:-0.1;qclock:0;ta rget:2;name:;Sex:;BirthDate:;operatorID:;SN:024000G0900046;version:V2.8.0.09}"

if result.startswith("result{") and result.endswith("}"):
    result = result[(result.index("{") + 1):result.index("}")]
# else:
#    raise ValueError("Invalid data '" + result + "'")

# Separate fields
fields = result.split(";")
# Separate field names and values
# First part is the name of the field for sure, but any additional ":" must not be split, as example "date:dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM" -> "date": "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM"
fields = [field.split(":", 1) for field in fields]
fields = {field[0]: field[1] for field in fields}

a = fields['type'].split("/")

print(fields)
pprint(fields)
print(a)
```

The result:

```
{'type': 'PT/APTT', 'error': '0', 'PT': '32.3 s', 'INR': '0.0', 'APTT': '119.2', 'code': '470433200', 'lot': '405 4H0401', 'date': '20/01/2017 06:47', 'PID': 'TREKKER20', 'index': '015', 'C1': '-0.1', 'C2': '-0.1', 'qclock': '0', 'ta rget': '2', 'name': '', 'Sex': '', 'BirthDate': '', 'operatorID': '', 'SN': '024000G0900046', 'version': 'V2.8.0.09'}
{'APTT': '119.2',
 'BirthDate': '',
 'C1': '-0.1',
 'C2': '-0.1',
 'INR': '0.0',
 'PID': 'TREKKER20',
 'PT': '32.3 s',
 'SN': '024000G0900046',
 'Sex': '',
 'code': '470433200',
 'date': '20/01/2017 06:47',
 'error': '0',
 'index': '015',
 'lot': '405 4H0401',
 'name': '',
 'operatorID': '',
 'qclock': '0',
 'ta rget': '2',
 'type': 'PT/APTT',
 'version': 'V2.8.0.09'}
['PT', 'APTT']
```

Note that dictionaries are not sorted (they don't need to be in most cases as you access the fields by the keys).

Comment: thanks   it runs my script but im now getting an error it says 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attirbute 'str'

Comment: Which statement gives you the error? Also note that I corrected my typo (edited) in the line `fields = {field[0]: field[1] for field in fields}`, it was `field[1:]` instead of `field[1]`, however that does not cause this error when I run this with Python 3.6.1.

Comment: it gives me the error on the statement 
fields = result.split(";")

i am using python 2 could that be the issue?

Comment: That is strange. I copy-pasted the code above to the [online python 2.7.10 interpreter](https://repl.it/JlEa/0) and it gives the same result. Try `print(result)` (or `print result`) right above statement throwing the error to check what exactly is your input.

Comment: ah yes i see, i have no idea why it still keeps giving me the same error.. it could be that it is picking up fault from the rest of my code?

Comment: Possible. Maybe you have some bugs when receiving data - are you sure that your data is always in exactly this format? You can paste the output of the `print result` (when the error occurs) here.

Comment: it only gives me the results that are in the result = how do i change it so any results in that format will come out with that, so if the PID is different it updates to the correct one

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you completely. Do you have any data specifications or examples what are some different forms of the data you can get? If `PID` is different, they it is just different and instead of `'PID': 'TREKKER20',` you would get e.g. `'PID': 'SOMETHINGDIFFERENT',` in the result.

Comment: so the field names will be the same just the data will be different so the date, the time the PID the code and so fourth so yes it would be PID: SOMETHINGDFFERENT

Comment: Yes, that is correct. This program just parses anything you give to it in the form: `result{field_name:field_value;field_name2:field:value:2;anything:anything}`,... Fields must be enclosed in `result{...}` and every filed is in form `name:value`. Fields are delimited with `;`. Any data in that form will be parsed in the dictionary, keys being field names and values anything after `:`. In example above: dict would be `{"field_name": "field_value", "field_name2": "field:value:2", "anything": "anything"}`.

Comment: that does not work instead it puts fieldname:fieldvalue in place of what ever should actually be there; output looks like this https://repl.it/JlEa/0

Comment: I am a bit lost. I made an example with different fields and different values: https://repl.it/JlEa/1

Comment: basically, the field name will always be the same but the field value will always be different so i need the code to pick up the different field values each time;

https://repl.it/JlEa/1

Comment: That makes sense and I think that is also what we all understood. So, where is the problem, if any? Note: If you change a code on my repl.it URL and send me the same URL back, I will not see your changes. You need to click share, then save button again to get new URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the results by semicolon:

```
result_array = result.split(';')
```

In results_array you'll get all strings separated by semicolon, then you can access the date there: `result_array[index]`

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a bad format to store data as fields might have colons in their values, but if you have to - you can strip away the surrounding result, split the rest on a semicolon, then do a single split on a colon to get `dict` key-value pairs and then just build a `dict` from that, e.g.:

```
data = "result{type:PT/APTT;error:0;PT:32.3 s;INR:0.0;APTT:119.2;code:470433200;lot:405 " \
       "4H0401;date:20/01/2017 06:47;PID:TREKKER20;index:015;C1:-0.1;C2:-0.1;qclock:0;ta " \
       "rget:2;name:;Sex:;BirthDate:;operatorID:;SN:024000G0900046;version:V2.8.0.09}"

parsed = dict(e.split(":", 1) for e in data[7:-1].split(";"))

print(parsed["APTT"])  # 119.2
print(parsed["PT"])  # 32.3 s
print(parsed["date"])  # 20/01/2017 06:47
```

If you need to further separate the date field to date and time, you can just do `date, time = parsed["date"].split()`, although if you're going to manipulate the object I'd suggest you to use the `datetime` module and parse it e.g.:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(parsed["date"], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
print(date)  # 2017-01-20 06:47:00
print(date.year)  # 2017
print(date.hour)  # 6
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

To go straight to the point and get your type, PT, APTT, date and time, use re:

```
import re
from source import result_gen

result = result_gen() 
def from_result(*vars):
    regex = re.compile('|'.join([f'{re.encode(var)}:.*?;' for var in vars]))
    matches =dict(f.group().split(':', 1) for f in re.finditer(regex, result)) 
    return tuple(matches[v][:-1] for v in vars) 

type, PT, APTT, datetime = from_result('type', 'PT', 'APTT', 'date') 
date, time = datetime.split()
```

Notice that this can be easily extended in the event you became suddenly interested in some other 'var' in the string...

In short you can optimize this further (to avoid the split step) by capturing groups in the regex search...

Comment: That's incredibly wasteful, and Python 3.6+ only to boot.

Comment: @zwer which is more wasteful: processing the entire string or just going straight to the data you want?  You can easily replace the formatted string with str.format or some other old style. Python 3.6 has been around forever in any case...

Comment: It's incredibly wasteful to use regex this way - you're also processing the entire string (at least up until the match) and 4 times at that (or more, performance is input-vars dependent) you just don't notice it directly as the regex engine runs on the C side. This might, just might, end up executing faster (again, thanks to the C side) than splitting for a couple of values but for every additional value it will experience more-than-a-linear slowdown. If you want to do it picking up variables one by one you might as well use native string search, it will end up several times faster than regex.

Comment: Also, Python 3.6 has been around for barely 8 months, unless you're a mayfly that hardly classifies as _forever_.

Comment: What are you even on about? So because it's only python 3.6 we should not use a convenience provided for us? I have already said of the alternatives you could use if you envisage your code running in older versions. That's not a problem at all. I don't like tend to give stuff to always be used verbatim. I prefer to give sound and comprehensive hint...

Comment: And about the matter of efficiency, I have added a note to my answer. The reset approach IS more efficient than processing the whole string when done COMPLETELY. Let me now do it completely to be comprehensive enough...